# Question in installing PostgreSql via Homebrew in MacOS

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I install and setup PostgreSql via Homebrew, my OS is MacOS.

Command:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Install succeed and it say 'This formula has created a default database cluster with:
initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres', then I exec command `createdb` to create db but it requires password, see that:

```
kevin@mac postgres % createdb
Password:
Password:
createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "kevin"
```

I input my computer's password but it failed to login, it confused me, I haven't create any account so what is the **correct password** here?

Answer (score -1):

I am just going through the same here (as I am trying to migrate something from postgres to mysql which seems to be a bit of a hassle) ... according to the below resource, you might need to run

```
psql postgres
```

and then create a user first?

https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/mac/how-to-install-postgresql-on-mac.html